# Show data from api to a table in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, routes, vue-component

How do i display data from the database. I have fetched data as an object when displaying it works well but when i convert the data to array it does not display the content of the table.

Am also trying to implement the routing such that when one clicks the button on the Actions column it redirect to another page that has a specific user details.

Am getting the data from the API and in the network fetch xhr am able to see the data.

This is the vue template where i want to display the data received by the API I guess am going wrong somewhere

```html
<v-data-table hide-actions flat :headers="headers" :="doctors">
        <template v-slot:items="props">
          <td>{{ props.index + 1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.full_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.email }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.username }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.username }}</td>
         <td> 
          <v-btn outline small color="indigo" @click="view(props.item)">
                                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> &nbsp; make payment
                            </v-btn>
         </td>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:no-results>
          <h6 class="grey--text">No data available</h6>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      page: 1,
      dateFormat: "DD MMM, YYYY",
      selected: null,
      dialog: false,
      loading: false,
      saveLoader: false,
      headers: [
        {text: "#", value: ""},
        {text: "name", value: "name"},
        {text: "email", value: "email"},
        {text: "role", value: "role"},
        {text: "updated_at", value: "updated_at"},
        {text: "Action", value: "action"},
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      doctors: "getListDoctors",
    }),
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
     fetchDoctors: 'setListDoctors'
      
    }),
    view(id) {
            this.$router.push({ path: `/finance/pay-doctors/${item.id, '_blank'}` });
        }
  },
  mounted() {
   this.fetchDoctors();
  },
}
</script>
```

Here is sample of data received from the API

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "TEST JOHN",
            "full_name": "Mrs. JOHN",
            "mobile": "0700000001",
            "email": "TEST@TEST.com",
            "active": 0,
            "created_at": "Sep 10, 2019 07:01:43 am",
            "roles": "testpharm",
            "username": "USER1"
        },
]
}
```

[image: this is the data received in the network part of browser]

Comment: Did you tried to iterate on the data with something like `v-for="item in data.data`? What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Comment: Also, I recommend that you use `async mounted` + `await this.fetchDoctors()`.

Comment: argh, i have formatted code but suggested edit queue is full (,:

Comment: https://codeshare.io/QnJQLJ you can share here @ericmp

Comment: @peninakinanu it's just the same code, but formatted, nothing special

Comment: "Am also trying to implement the routing such that when one clicks the button on the Actions column it redirect to another page that has a specific user details", that one is probably for another question.

Comment: ```Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object``` Getting this in console

Comment: Haha, we will need quite more context here. The error is quite self-explanatory too: you're passing down an object, but you're saying that the prop should receive an array. Depending on where that one is coming from, you should pick Array or Object (cannot say without more context).

Comment: how do i access now as an object? It displayed when i passed as an array @kissu

Comment: I have no idea as of what/where you do have that one. Please check my answer or edit your question with the relevant parts to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine regarding [the doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#header)

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table hide-actions flat :headers="headers" :items="doctors" :items-per-page="5">
    <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.full_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.mobile }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.email }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.username }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:no-results>
      <h6 class="grey--text">No data available</h6>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: "#", value: "" },
        { text: "name", value: "name" },
        { text: "email", value: "email" },
        { text: "role", value: "role" },
        { text: "updated_at", value: "updated_at" },
        { text: "Action", value: "action" },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      doctors: "getListDoctors",
    }),
  },

  async mounted() {
    await this.fetchDoctors();
  },
}
</script>
```

---

Use your Vue devtools to be sure to pass `data.data` to the final `doctors` Vuex getter (regarding your JSON example).
Vue devtools will help you see what state you currently have + the usage of the network tab can also help quite a lot.